# data driven testing approach and tools

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I have a new task on hand to design a new test suit for a application driven by huge data(from teradata, ms sql and mysql). we generally use regression testing to compare tables A-B,B-A . is there a better approach for data driven testing or any open source tool that you know about which can help me do that?

thank you ,for your time

Comment: Please explain little more about the context like what you are going to test etc.

Comment: There is input data mostly numbers like sales and units,which is transformed by a process .so input values changes ex: sales becomes revenue ..i should be checking if this transformation of data is correct and it's real huge data not just sales to revenue.so any check must be based around what data was and what has it transformed to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many approaches to Data-driven testing (Selenium, Katalon Studio, JUnit, Protractor…), you can choose whatever you think that it may be fit with your team and your project. To me, as a codeless tester Katalon Studio is the easiest one for me to approach this kind of testing through some piece-of-cake steps:

[Data-driven testing approach with Katalon Studio](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/tutorials/data-driven-testing/)

If you have any concern about data-driven testing, ask below then I will try to answer ASAP.

Good luck!